# How to find last 7 days records using pig latin?

Tags: apache-pig, records, latin

I am a beginner to Pig latin. I have a requirement to find the last 7 days records from the csv with contains last 4 years of data.

Can anyone help me to understand this.

Comment: In what format is your Date or Timestamp column/columns? And do you need last 7 days per a key or any key?

Answer (score 1):

A more generic way is to compare each line of data and check if it is older than 7 days or not?
For this, we need to capture the date in each line of data. Let the set of data be a relation dataSet with a column field as date of chararray type.

In Pig 0.11 you can convert the date field from chararray to datetime data type using the ToDate() function, and then get the difference between the CurrentTime() and date using DaysBetween() and filter according to it. For example:

```
lastSevenDaysRec = FILTER dataSet BY DaysBetween(CurrentTime(), ToDate(date, 'yyyy MM dd')) <= 7
```

You can check the [following documentation](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html) for detailed understanding of different date time functions in Pig Latin. Also you can have a look at the valid formats to use in the ToDate function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your set of data is A and there is one line per day, and it has a field named date, you could try something similar to this:

```
B = GROUP A BY date;
B = ORDER A BY group DESC;
B = LIMIT B BY 7;
```

And then, you would have the last seven days records grouped per date.

Comment: What happens if there is 1000 records per each date?

Comment: Solved. You only need one group at the start.